# Why spot light coming through out the mesh

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

I have render with Eevee 2.82. Why the spot light coming through out the mesh. Any suggestion whats going wrong. Thanks
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have some orange lights in the scene? If so, what kind of lamps are they, and where are they located? If you don't, maybe try disabling certain materials and see if that changes anything. Does this happen if you use a single light source?

Comment: How about some more information about the scene and the light setup and so on? You seem to be around here long enough to know how to ask a good question, aren't you?

Comment: @metaphor_set plz check the question some images added